# landscape client not updating tags on landscape interface

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, landscape

I need to modify tags for computers (ubuntu 16.04) already registered on landscape. When i change the tag in /etc/landscape/client.conf and restart the service , i cannot see the updated new tag on landscape.

> systemctl restart landscape-client

When i try to run landscape-config on the client, i get a duplicate on landscape.

> landscape-config --silent

I want to update the tags on command line from clients side  so i can automate it , not thrrought the landscape interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, and its not possible to do that on command line but we can do it on the landscape interface or using api
https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/computers.html#addtagstocomputers